# Jmeter FTP request in passive mode

Tags: ftp, jmeter, passive-mode

I am sending an FTP request using `Jmeter`. I just set the IP address and the `jmeter` in default send the file on port 21 and the server does not accept the file. But I want the process be passive which means the client negotiate with the server and after assigning a port number the file be sent on that.
How should I set it in `Jmeter`?
Also I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622148/jmeter-active-ftp-to-vltrader) post which says the default mode is passive but it is not true for my case.

Comment: So, you want to get the port number first, and then pass it on the request. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

- JMeter establishes connection with the FTP server on port 21 (command channel). If your server is listening on the different port - use `Port Number` input to configure it.

  [image: JMeter FTP destination command port]
- JMeter is configured to use local passive mode as it evidenced by the next line:

  ```
   ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();// should probably come from the setup dialog
  ```

  in the [FTPSampler source code](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/trunk/src/protocol/ftp/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/ftp/sampler/FTPSampler.java)
- FTP server should tell JMeter a higher port for the data channel for file transfer

Assuming you

1. Provide path to existing local file
2. Tick `put(STOR)` box
3. If your file is not text-based tick `Use Binary mode`
4. Provide correct destination and credentials

you should be able to upload the file successfully. If you experience problems - implement the upload request using [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Apache Commons Net FTP](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) libraries and enable debug logging to see where exactly your problem is.

References:

- [Net/FrequentlyAskedQuestions](https://wiki.apache.org/commons/Net/FrequentlyAskedQuestions)
- [Load Testing FTP and SFTP Servers Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-ftp-and-sftp-servers-using-jmeter)
- [File Transfer Protocol specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959)

---

If you are not able to establish the connection with the FTP server on port 21 - you won't be able to proceed.

Comment: Thanks it was solved by setting the correct port number.