# Jmeter: FTP Request Sampler: " java.net.UnknownHostException"

Tags: ftp, jmeter

I am working on FTP Sampler and connecting with Public FTP Server

```
"ftp.swfwmd.state.fl.us" for "Get" method.
```

But `JMeter` is showing following error in `LOG`:

> Response code: 000 Response message: java.net.UnknownHostException: 
>   ftp.swfwmd.state.fl.us

Please help me out in this problem.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622148/jmeter-active-ftp-to-vltrader/9671136#9671136

Answer (score 0):

The message indicate host is not known from your machine.

So check your DNS or add manually an entry in your DNS.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try accessing the server using IP address instead of hostname - `204.76.241.31`
2. If point 1 doesn't help most probably you are sitting behind corporate firewall. For HTTP-based samplers you can specify proxy server details by adding the next lines to *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   ftp.proxyHost=hostname or IP address of your proxy
   ftp.proxyPort=port of your proxy server
   ```

   if above doesn't help you can try setting the following properties instead:

   ```
   socksProxyHost=hostname or IP address of your proxy
   socksProxyPort=port of your proxy server (normally 1080)
   ```

   JMeter restart will be required to pick the properties up

References:

- [Java Networking Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html)
- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Load Testing FTP and SFTP Servers Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-ftp-and-sftp-servers-using-jmeter)